# what is retrofit interceptor , can we have multiple?

Tags: android, retrofit

I can not understand the retrofit interceptors ,

```
 private val OkHttpClient by  lazy {
        okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor {
                    onOnIntercept(it)
                }
                .addInterceptor(LoggingInterceptor())
                .addInterceptor(getInterceptor404())
                .callTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
             //   .addInterceptor(TimeoutInterceptor())


                .build()
    }
```

and what do these lines do, and If I have, multiple does the speed down?

```
 val response: Response = chain.proceed(chain.request())
   

 return chain.proceed(chain.request())
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use multiple interceptors.  When you do a request calling interface method using retrofit, your request go to the interceptor and then continue.  In the interceptor you can rewrite or retry request.  For example, you could add the access token in all request and refresh the token if is necessary, add the headers, another bodies, etc. When you received a response from api, the interceptor intercept the response too.  But please, read the documentation to understand how it works.  Have a nice coding!